# Change CSS selection color of PHP text margins

Tags: php, css, text, colors, selection

I got this piece of CSS for changing the selection color of text:

```
::selection 
{
background:#e56617
}
```

But, it doesn't work for the text margin color of PHP values.
For example, something like this:

```
echo $user->username;
```

when selected looks like this:

http://postimg.org/image/cuhrh5ygx/

The selection of text is orange, as intended, but the selection margins are blue as they are by default.
The above problem does not happen when normal html text is in question.

P.S. There are no breaks in the code as answers in other similar questions have indicated and adding webkit or body in the css selection tag doesn't fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's the default behavior in most GUIs - when selecting text, the background becomes the "negative" color of the selection color. "not blue" is "orange".

Comment: Oh, is there a way to change it? And how come the same color does not appear when selecting normal text?

Comment: the browser has absolutely no way of knowing what text was output by PHP, and what happened to just be some html around the php. It just sees a blob of text/html. If you get different behavior, then look at the structure of the page and the css that's applied to the "weird" text in question.

Comment: Do you want the whole line that 'News 1' is on to switch to orange instead of just the the background of the text 'News 1'?  Can you show your html (page source)?  It's the background of the containing element you're going to want to change, most likely.

Comment: Many thanks to Marc B and Barbara Laird!

The problem was in the HTML/CSS as their answers indicated.
It occurred because none of the echoed PHP values had paragraph (or any for that matter) tags. The selection color somehow didn't affect the text margins because of that.